# Slow loading of treeview

Tags: c#, performance, list, treeview, loading

I am currently having hard time with Treeview loading. My application has a central panel where multiple user controls are loaded. Each one got a treeview of 5 parent nodes (Groups) owning tens of children nodes (Persons) with a total of 50 nodes.
Same function load the treeview (see down here) :
First loop is adding the Groups and the second loop (into the first) adds the Persons.

That function takes about 10 seconds to load 50 nodes. Which is an eternity in my world.

Don't know what to do to enhance this one. Please have a look at this function.

```
    public static List<TreeNode> ArbreCommun(Guid idUser)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

        stopWatch.Start();


        List<TreeNode> ArbreParent = new List<TreeNode>();

        using (bdd_compactEntities contexte = new bdd_compactEntities())
        {
            if (contexte.Groupe.Count() > 0)
                foreach (Groupe grpItem in contexte.Groupe)
                {
                    if (grpItem.g_nom == "Tous")
                    {
                        TreeNode Tous = new TreeNode();
                        Tous.Text = grpItem.g_nom + " (" + contexte.Personne.Count() + ")";
                        Tous.Tag = grpItem.id;
                        Tous.ToolTipText = "ID groupe = " + grpItem.id;
                        Tous.ImageKey = "group";
                        Tous.SelectedImageKey = "group";

                        foreach (Personne pers in FonctionsYou.ChargementPersonnesTous())
                        {
                            TreeNode PersonneNode = new TreeNode();
                            PersonneNode.Text = pers.p_nom + " " + pers.p_prenom;
                            PersonneNode.Tag = pers.id;
                            PersonneNode.ToolTipText = "ID personne = " + pers.id;

                            if (FonctionsYou.HasGroupe(idUser, FonctionsYou.GetGroupeIdPers(pers.id)))
                            {
                                if (FonctionsYou.CheckDisponibiliteAthlete(pers.id))
                                {
                                    PersonneNode.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                                    PersonneNode.ImageKey = "dispo";
                                    PersonneNode.SelectedImageKey = "dispo";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    PersonneNode.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                                    PersonneNode.ImageKey = "blesse";
                                    PersonneNode.SelectedImageKey = "blesse";
                                }
                            }

                            Tous.Nodes.Add(PersonneNode);
                        }

                        ArbreParent.Add(Tous);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TreeNode GroupeNode = new TreeNode();
                        GroupeNode.Text = grpItem.g_nom + " (" + grpItem.Personne.Count() + ")";
                        GroupeNode.Tag = grpItem.id;
                        GroupeNode.ToolTipText = "ID groupe = " + grpItem.id;
                        GroupeNode.ImageKey = "group";
                        GroupeNode.SelectedImageKey = "group";
                        if (FonctionsYou.HasGroupe(idUser, grpItem.id))
                        {
                            GroupeNode.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                        }

                        foreach (Personne pers in contexte.Personne.Where(x => x.Groupe_id == grpItem.id))
                        {
                            TreeNode PersonneNode = new TreeNode();
                            PersonneNode.Text = pers.p_nom + " " + pers.p_prenom;
                            PersonneNode.Tag = pers.id;
                            PersonneNode.ToolTipText = "ID personne = " + pers.id;

                            if (FonctionsYou.HasGroupe(idUser, FonctionsYou.GetGroupeIdPers(pers.id)))
                            {
                                if (FonctionsYou.CheckDisponibiliteAthlete(pers.id))
                                {
                                    PersonneNode.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                                    PersonneNode.ImageKey = "dispo";
                                    PersonneNode.SelectedImageKey = "dispo";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    PersonneNode.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                                    PersonneNode.ImageKey = "blesse";
                                    PersonneNode.SelectedImageKey = "blesse";
                                }
                            }

                            GroupeNode.Nodes.Add(PersonneNode);
                        }
                        ArbreParent.Add(GroupeNode);

                    }
                }
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
        return ArbreParent;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in you TreeView? Will it be much faster if you comment all lines where you work with nodes keeping all external methods calling, e.g. 'FonctionsYou.HasGroupe', 'FonctionsYou.GetGroupeIdPers' and so on?

Comment: You are actually right, one of them functions is slowing the sh*t out of the whole thing... I am gonna work it out. Thank you for your help bro !

Comment: Thank you sir, I managed to get down from 10seconds to one second.

Comment: You are welcome :) it just seemed strange to be slow on 50 nodes

Answer (score 2):

By the way, here is my calling method :

```
            List<TreeNode> _itemsNodes = FonctionsYou.ArbreCommun(userConnecte.uid);
            treeview_arbre.ImageList = FonctionsYou.GetImageListTV();
            // Display a wait cursor while the TreeNodes are being created.
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            // Suppress repainting the TreeView until all the objects have been created.
            treeview_arbre.BeginUpdate();

            foreach (TreeNode node in _itemsNodes)
            {
                treeview_arbre.Nodes.Add(node);
            }

            // Reset the cursor to the default for all controls.
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

            // Begin repainting the TreeView.
            treeview_arbre.EndUpdate();
```